# Azure Web Site deployment very slow

Tags: git, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have an Azure Website which is deployed automatically by our GitLab server. Compared to other projects we deploy with the same scripts, this one takes a really long time do deploy (15-20 minutes). Other projects are usually deployed within 1-2 minutes. (Given approximately the same amount of modifications.)

The step which takes most of the time is `Handling Basic Web Site deployment`. All other steps are finished within seconds.

The log after `git push` to Azure looks like this (timestamps from the SCM site added by me):

```
[2016-08-25T07:42:15.6465159Z] remote: Updating branch 'master'.
[2016-08-25T07:42:18.2159075Z] remote: Updating submodules.
[2016-08-25T07:42:18.2783580Z] remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '2a71d1ddd3'.
[2016-08-25T07:42:18.6221285Z] remote: Generating deployment script.
[2016-08-25T07:42:18.7658033Z] remote: Running deployment command...
[2016-08-25T07:42:19.8283917Z] remote: Handling Basic Web Site deployment.
[                            ] remote: ..... [1051 dots here]
[2016-08-25T08:00:12.4710682Z] remote: KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
[2016-08-25T08:00:12.5492017Z] remote: Copying file: '[first file]'
[2016-08-25T08:00:12.7054553Z] remote: Copying file: '[last file]'
[2016-08-25T08:00:12.7210814Z] remote: Finished successfully.
[2016-08-25T08:00:12.8492401Z] remote: Running post deployment command(s)...
[2016-08-25T08:00:13.0805168Z] remote: Deployment successful.
```

I have no idea what is causing this massive delay. Also, the delay is never the same, it varies by a few minutes.

Since I don't know which information is important and I can't post *all* information about our project or the Azure Web Site here, please ask for what you need to help me, and I'll edit my question to provide the necessary information.

Comment: Does it have an extremely large number of files?

Comment: @DavidEbbo No, the repository I'm pushing consists of 335 files in total (12 modified). One of the projects that takes only 2 minutes to deploy has 580 files.

Comment: That's odd. And it happens consistently on that one? Can you share your web app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it happens consistently. It also does in the "staging" slot. I created a dummy web app called `dummy160829`. The app with the deployment problem is not the "master". (The master app deployment takes less than a minute.) At 08:00Z today, I will perform another deployment since we have a scheduled update for the production slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you have an extremely large number of files under your `D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data` folders. Looks like several hundreds of thousands!

They are named something like `error-2015-02-22235701Z-2ab04577-57f6-43cb-b09a-cc71e354e2f2.xml`. Many are very old, going back to 2014.

Given that you probably don't need these files, try the following:

- In Kudu Console, go to `D:\home\site\wwwroot`. Don't try to go into App_Data, as the number of files will cause it to hang.
- Run `del App_Data\error*.xml`

Expect it to take a very long time! One way to check that it's making progress is to open another Kudu Console instance (in another tab), go to `D:\home` and just run `dir`, which tells you how much space is left. That should be going up.

And obviously, you'll need to look into what's causing these files to be created in the first place, so it doesn't keep happening.

Comment: I don't need (all of) these files, indeed. Thanks for investigating! I'm currently removing the files. It appears to be a misconfiguration of [elmah](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/). The errors should be logged to a database instead of XML files (where the clean-up process takes place). And I have to check why there are so many of them, of course.

Comment: After having deleted around 8 GB of unnecessary log files in staging and production, I deployed a staging build and it took less than a minute. I guess my problem is solved. Thank you! By the way, I think the errors appeared due to the "always on" feature because it uses the default host name to keep the web site alive, but our app doesn't like the `.azurewebsites.net` name. (Shouldn't have produced this much output though.)